# mysql missing semicolon Why?

Tags: mysql

missing semicolon

```
delimiter $$
create procedure SP_ADD_USER( IN nom varchar(45), IN turn varchar(45), IN age int(11), in price int(11), in dates varchar(45))
begin insert into datos
(nombre, turno, edad, precio, fecha) 
values 
(nom ,turn, age, price, dates) missing semicolon in this ``

end $$
delimiter;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon because you're expected to delimit each statement with a semicolon. From [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/entering-queries.html):

> A query normally consists of an SQL statement followed by a
>   semicolon. [...]

The new delimiter you define in the first row is applied to the "outer" statement, that is the procedure creation; this way the interpreter knows where a piece of the procedure ends and where the whole procedure ends.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure SP_ADD_USER (
    IN nom varchar(45),
    IN turn varchar(45),
    IN age int(11),
    IN price int(11), 
    IN dates varchar(45))
begin
    insert into datos (nombre, turno, edad, precio, fecha) 
    values (nom ,turn, age, price, dates);
end $$
delimiter;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, really thanks if I'm very stupid forgive me is that I'm starting but it will be better